# Animating text transformation

Tags: css, animation, transformation

> How can i use html/css transformation on a paragraph like this so that it is transformed into two (or more) parts, the second part being slightly indented? The first version of this text shows the initial text, the second version shows how it should look after animation (ignoring the blockquote markers)

> How can i use html/css transformation on a paragraph like this so that it is transformed into two (or more) parts, the second part being slightly indented? The first version of this text shows the initial text,
>
> > the second version shows how it should look after animation (ignoring the blockquote markers)

The ideas I have had so far involves a change from inline to inline-block, but I believe that change cannot be animated via CSS transformation. A solution involving JavaScript is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got you or not and what kind of animation you want, but is it something you're looking for?

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // calculate how much the second span should be pushed
  const indent = document.querySelector('.indent');
  if (indent) {
    const { left } = indent.getBoundingClientRect();
    const { offsetWidth } = indent.parentElement;
    indent.style.setProperty('--indent', offsetWidth - left + 'px');
  }
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('p').classList.toggle('on');
});
```

```css
p {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px
  vertical-align: top;
}

.indent {
  margin-right: 0px;
  transition: margin-right ease-in-out 1s;
}

.indent + * {
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: margin ease-in-out 1s;
}

.on .indent {
  margin-right: var(--indent);
}

.on .indent + * {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>How can i use html/css transformation on a paragraph like this so that it is transformed into two (or more) parts, the second part being slightly intended? The first version of this text shows the initial text, </span><span class="indent"></span><span>the second version shows how it should look after animation (ignoring the blockquote markers)</span>
</p>

<button>Toggle</button>
```

Comment: This works well, except that the second part should be indented. (As opposed to "intended" as I wrote in the question... :) )

Comment: The challenge is to indent the whole second part, not only the first line. The only solution I have found is to use display:inline-block, but that breaks the animation.